# process.start launches exe twice

Tags: vb.net, winforms, process.start

I hope this is something someone can help me resolve.  I am attempting to run a DART Bundle using the Cisco AnyConnect Built in tool in a Windows Form.  When I call the exe, using Process.Start or System.Diagnostics.Process.Start, in a click event it duplicates the command.  I then have the process running twice at the same time.  I can call the Cisco Connection GUI with no problems using Process.Start.  The code is below.  Also is there a way to delay the MsgBox("Text written to file") until after the DART Bundle has completed?

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\dart\dartcli.exe")
        MsgBox("Text written to file")
        Button7.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I seem to have found out why I was having the issue.  When I created the button I had an error with the click event name (Duplicated the name by accident) and I had Visual Studio Express automatically correct the issues.  It added a handler at the end of the button click event which was causing the button to call the code twice.  I removed the handler and it stopped calling twice.

I went from this

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\dart\dartcli.exe")
    MsgBox("Text written to file")
    Button7.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green
End Sub
```

To this.  Problem Solved

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\dart\dartcli.exe")
    MsgBox("Text written to file")
    Button7.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green
End Sub
```

Thanks everyone for their time and help!

Answer (score 1):

Probably, Process start is not called twice but the event fired twice. 
Place a breakpoint and check it.
If yes, then you can easily find the problem in call stack.

And, yes, you can delay the message. 
As I understand, this DART Bundle executes, outputs data to file and exits.

So, you can use the following code to solve the problem. It's in C# but it should be the same or similar in VB.NET.

```
Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\dart\dartcli.exe");
Process.WaitForExit();
MessageBox.Show("Text written to file.");
```

WaitForExit() will synchronously wait until the process ends.
Or you can subscribe to Process.Exited event if you don't want your application to be blocked.

```
private void YourMethod()
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\dart\dartcli.exe";
    process.Exited += new EventHandler(Process_Exited);
    process.Start();
}

private void Process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    MessageBox.Show("Text written to file");
}
```

Comment: I put in a break point and I see that it launches the button event again after the button color change.  The break will stop at `Button7.Background.System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green` then when I click continue it starts the dartcli.exe over again.  How do I find the call stack to correct this?  Please forgive me ignorance I am new to programming in VB.  Thanks

Comment: I actually just tried to rewrite the command this way `Dim dart As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\dart\dartcli.exe")
        dart.WaitForExit()` but it still launches the event twice.  It also calls the entire form up again.  So now I have the process running twice and two forms on the screen.

Comment: @LordDaius Can you upload full form .cs and .designer.cs files. You can use pastebin.com to do it.

Comment: @D0KZ I can't use pastebin.com the company firewall blocks it.  Is there a better way to paste the forms?  They are xaml.vb and xaml

Comment: Thanks for the `Waitforexit()` command.  Now that the program stopped calling the event twice it works like a charm.